# Copy a NB.SI formula into a Google Sheets sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am turning to you today for help with a problem on Google Sheets.

I receive this data from a Google Sheets form: An answer (0 or 1) to 5 different questions.
I would like to calculate in column A (in green) the scores out of 5 for each row, as soon as a new row is added by the form.

[image: Sheet without notes]

I tried to use the `ARRAYFORMULA()` function but it does the count for all the cells in the range and not just row by row:

[image]

Do you have an idea to have a score out of 5 for each line of question and have it apply to the whole file as soon as a new line is added by the Google Form?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `COUNTIF` (English correspondance for `NB.SI`), modify your formula to:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(IF(B1:F=1,ROW(B1:B)), ROW(B1:B)))`

or for your regional settings:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(NB.SI(IF(B1:F=1,ROW(B1:B)), ROW(B1:B)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can get a row-by-row sum with `sumif()` like this in cell A3:

```
=arrayformula( sumif( if(column(B3:F), row(B3:F)), row(B3:F), B3:F) )
```

This formula uses open-ended range references so it will create results all the way down to the end of the sheet. To limit that, use a range reference like `B3:F100` instead.